# How to read from txt file via filereader and write a modified?

Tags: split, java-8, filereader, java-io, filewriter

I have to read a txt file via filereader and make a censoring by removing all words starts with "c" and "C" and write it by creating a new txt file as censored. I have done below, but I need to make the reading andwrinting in one method using Stream().
I have done smtg similar but it must be with stream and not by creating different lists and char arrays ect.

I have done smtg similar but it must be with stream and not by creating different lists and char arrays ect.

```
public class Censored {
    static String words = "";
    static String censoredWords = "";
    static List<String> myWords = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        System.out.println(censorTxt());
        convertListToStringAndChar();
    }

    private static List<String> censorTxt() {
        try (
                FileReader in = new FileReader("resources/input.txt");
                ){          
            int read = 0;
            while (read != -1) {
                read = in.read();
                String myChar = Character.toString((char) read);                 
                String word = myChar;
                words = words + word;
            }
            String[] splitedTextArray = words.split(" ");
            for (String elements : splitedTextArray) {
                if (!elements.startsWith("c")) {                    
                    myWords.add(elements);
                }
            }
            return myWords;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("smtg went wrong");
        }
        return null;
    }

    private static void convertListToStringAndChar() {
        try {
            FileWriter out = new FileWriter("resources/censored_content.txt");
            for (String strings : myWords) {
                
                censoredWords += strings;
            }
            for (int i = 0 ; i < censoredWords.length() ; i++) {
                int c = censoredWords.charAt(i);                
                out.write(c);                   
            }               
            out.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }       
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code suggests that the files do not contain line breaks. Is that intentional? Besides that, you should first learn about [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html), [methods for writing strings](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/io/Writer.html#write(java.lang.String)) or [arrays](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/io/Writer.html#write(char%5B%5D)), and [reading arrays](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/io/Reader.html#read(char%5B%5D))

Comment: …to stop your habit of processing data in single char operations and performing unnecessary string concatenation. And check the correctness of your code before considering rewriting it just to use another API. E.g. you’re splitting the text into words at space characters but concatenate the words without space characters. I just noticed that you are using try-with-resources for the reader, so why don’t you use it for the writer?

Comment: The time to test the result of `read()` is immediately *after* you call it, not before, and not after you've done a whole lot of things you shouldn't have done at end of stream. Your loop should be `while ((read = in.read()) != -1)`.

Answer (score 0):

Possible implementation using `Files.lines()` providing a stream of strings in the input file.

No intermediate list is created here, the censored words are written into the specific text file.

```java
public static void readAndFilter(String inputFile, String outputFile) throws IOException {
    try (BufferedWriter writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(Paths.get(outputFile), StandardOpenOption.CREATE);
         Stream<String> input = Files.lines(Paths.get(inputFile))) {
            input
             .flatMap(line -> Arrays.stream(line.split("\\s+")))
             .filter(word -> !word.isEmpty())
             .filter(word -> 'c' == Character.toLowerCase(word.charAt(0)))
             .forEach(censored -> {
                 try {
                     writer.write(censored);
                     writer.newLine();
                 } catch (IOException ioex) {
                     System.err.println(ioex);
                 }
             });
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    readAndFilter("my_input.txt", "censored.txt");
}
```